# Fancybox is not working on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have added fancybox to my site but every way I try it just won't work. All it does is just open the image in a new window! I am only calling jQuery once. The only thing I can think is it's conflicting with the other JavaScript code in my site.

When I run the page using Firebug I get the error: "type error fancybox is not a function". All code is in end of head tag.

Here is code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="js/libs/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/linked _big.png"><img src="images/linked.png" alt="linked" /></a>
```

Comment: Can you give us the link to the page?

Comment: you didn't forget to load jQuery, did you? I don't see it in your code above unless is embedded in another js file. Also check your fancybox paths. This `/fancybox/source/...` means that fancybox folder is located at the root

Comment: sorry i did load the jquery before the javascript files i just forgot to put it in: <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>;
and yes my fancybox folder is located in the root.
I dont have a web host to upload the page at the moment is there another way i can do it?

Comment: this `fancybox is not a function` error is typical when fancybox js file is not loaded so I insist : "check your paths" otherwise we don't have ways to help you

Comment: i solved it, it was to do with the paths..that little slash at the beginning. feel stupid now. thanks for your help though much appreciated!